# How to return list of one-to-one relation objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model named Profile which is OneToOne related to User model. Profile has ManyToMany Field named muting_users.

I need to return list of muting_users from API View show below but I only managed to return list of Profiles.

How can I return list of users in listed case(code below)?

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    muting_users = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank = True, related_name = 'muted_by', symmetrical = False)
```

```
class MutingUserListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        request_user = self.request.user
        return request_user.profile.muting_users.all() # < it returning list of Profile but should return list of Users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the users using the relationship like so:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    request_user = self.request.user
    return User.objects.filter(profile__in=request_user.profile.muting_users.all())
```

This way, you can get the data from the db in two goes which will return a queryset so you can chain other functions like `count`, or further filters, etc.

Comment: "In two goes". One for muting_users and another one for users.

Comment: Yeah. Haha. In 2 goes, rather.

Comment: I needed to add .all() after profile__in=request_user.profile.muting_users just for everyone to know

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user for each muted profile:

```py
def get_queryset(self):
    request_user = self.request.user
    muted_profiles = request_user.profile.muting_users.all()
    muted_users = [profile.user for profile in muted_profiles] # (*1)
    return muted_users
```

(*1) Be free to [optimize code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to avoid a db request for each profile:

```py
muted_profiles = (
    request_user
   .profile
   .muting_users
   .select_related('user') # <-- this
   .all()   
)
```